# java String Numeric Comparator to Sort DropDownlist

Tags: java, comparator

`String Numeric Comparator` to Sort DropDownlist:

List have Ex: `1 per 1 months`,`1 per 2 months`......`2 per 12 months`

I tried `StringComparator`, `String Numeric Comparator`, `NumericComparator`, `Split Comparator` but didn't worked,Any Suggestions

Comment: Give a more suggestive example,a before and after example would help.

Comment: Please give your code example too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom implementation of Comparator will help you:

```
Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<String>() {
  public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    // TODO
  }
};
```

Comment: i have done same implementation in stringNumeric and spilt comparator by custom but no luck it is not sorted.

Comment: Provide an example of what you mean by "sorted".

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own comparator. First you have to calculate x / y where the text is *x per y months*. Then you only have to compare x1/y1 with x2/y2.

```
Comparator<String> comp = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        Double d1 = calcValue(o1);
        Double d2 = calcValue(o2);
        return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }

    private Double calcValue(String s) {
         Double x, y;
         // extract x and y from String s
         ...
         return x / y;
    }
};
```